# Sengrid templates with custom image for every email

Tags: python, sendgrid

How to send sengrid email with custom image which is inserto to template with tag?

I have transactional email and I want insert image of item user is interested.

I know how to add tags for custom information to template. But what about images?

Maybe is possible to do something like this:

```
personalization.add_substitution(Substitution("%image_url%", "http://some_url.to.image ))
```

And than in place of %image_url% insert image which will be presented in email?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how I'd do it.
`<img src="%image_url%">` in the Template, then populate it in the message you send.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I just need to create tag for image url.

```
personalization.add_substitution(Substitution("%image_url%", "http://some_url.to.image ))
```